# actual layout and graphical layout not correspond

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following XML code with hp bar and mana bar:

```
     <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/player_health"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/player_job"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:text="@string/player_health"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/background_health"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/player_health"
                android:background="@drawable/background_health_rectangle"/>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/health"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/background_health"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/background_health"
                android:layout_below="@+id/player_health"
                android:background="@drawable/health_rectangle" />

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/player_health_number"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_below="@+id/player_health"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/player_mana"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/health"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:text="@string/player_mana"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/background_mana"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/player_mana"
                android:background="@drawable/background_health_rectangle"/>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/mana"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/background_mana"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/background_mana"
                android:layout_below="@+id/player_mana"
                android:background="@drawable/mana_rectangle" />

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/player_mana_number"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_below="@+id/player_mana"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/> 

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/attribute"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/attribute_title"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mana"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

and the graphical layout in eclips is showing:

[image]

but what is showing on the actual device is very different:

[image]

I have no idea why it's like this, I tried many different things but non of them worked. It's the first time for me that the actual look and the graphical layout is so different.

oh, I almost forgot, here are the codes for the XML files of  background_health_rectangle:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#ff207d94" />
    <padding android:left="2dp"
        android:top="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:bottom="2dp" />
    <solid android:color="#ffffffff" />

</shape>
```

health_rectangle:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#ff207d94" />
    <padding android:left="2dp"
        android:top="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:bottom="2dp" />
    <solid android:color="#ffff0000" />

</shape>
```

mana_rectangle:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#ff207d94" />
    <padding android:left="2dp"
        android:top="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:bottom="2dp" />
    <solid android:color="#FF0000FF" />

</shape>
```

Comment: What is the top-level view group that all of these views are in (`RelativeLayout`, `LinearLayout`, etc.)?

Comment: try removing ff in start of color code for example $0000FF instead of #FF0000FF this may help try.

Comment: there are in scrollview, and there is relativelayout inside the scrollview

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it was a problem in the code, i used layout parameters to change the wide of the bars, and i accidently merge the two parameters. here is the correct code:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams health_params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)
                health_bar.getLayoutParams();
                float actual_health_percent = (actual_health/health)*200; 
                int health_value = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, actual_health_percent, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                health_params.width = health_value;
                health_bar.setLayoutParams(health_params);

                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mana_params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)
                mana_bar.getLayoutParams();
                float actual_mana_percent = (actual_mana/mana)*200; 
                int mana_value = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, actual_mana_percent, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                mana_params.width = mana_value;
                mana_bar.setLayoutParams(mana_params);
```